# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una lista con los elementos que están presentes en una lista pero en la otra no, con Python?

Tags: python

Como dije, ¿cómo podría hacer una lista de elementos que aparecen en la primera lista y no en la 2da y viceversa?

Aquí un ejemplo:

```
list1 = ['1','2','3','4','5']
list2 = ['1','7','8','3','2']
```

Lo que se espera que salga es: `['4','5']` en el primer caso,
y para el segundo caso me refiero a otra lista que contenga los elementos que aparecen en la 2da lista pero no en la primera, o sea esto: `['7','8']`.

Comment: los valores se pueden repetir?? ósea `list1 = ['1','1','2','3','4','5','5']`???

Comment: Si, no hay problema, puedo hacer que los repetidos desaparezcan, el problema es como separar lo que tiene uno y no el otro y viceversa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el caso de que los elementos no se repitan podríamos convertirlos a `set` y hacer las típicas operaciones de conjuntos.

```py
list1 = ['1','2','3','4','5']
list2 = ['1','7','8','3','2']

set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)

print(set1-set2)
```

Aquí hemos hecho la operación de diferencia de conjuntos, lo que da como resultado:

```
{'4', '5'}
```

Esto lo podemos llevar a una función para hacerlo más dinámico

```py
def diferencia(c1,c2):
    return set(c1)-set(c2) #list(set(c1)-set(c2))

print(diferencia(list2,list1))
```

Aquí se declara una función que recibirá 2 parámetros (en principio se piensa que sean listas). La función retorna el resultado de convertir a `set` y operar, ósea que se retorna el valor resultante de `set(c1)-set(c2)`.

Esto también lo puedes pasar a una función lambda para hacerlo más simplificado, pero por ahora lo dejo así.

**Resultado**

```
{'8', '7'}
```

Si quieres que el resultado sea una lista deberás convertirlo usando `list()` esto lo puedes agregar al momento de retornar el valor o al momento de imprimirlo.

Comment: Genial, gracias!
La parte en donde declaraste la función no la entendí muy bien, podrías explicármelo por favor? Lo demás si entendí y todo bien.

Comment: por su puesto ^_^

Comment: Listo, ahí edité la respuesta, si igual no te queda claro házmelo

Comment: Me parece muy buena tu explicación, el tema de función se me complica un poco siempre, pero tengo entendido que c1 y c2 son solo parámetros generales y luego cuando mandas el print de la función, remplazas los parámetros c1 y c2 por las listas originales, cierto? (perdón por responder recién, estuve ocupado con unos trabajos ayer)

Comment: Algo.. `c1` y `c2` tomarán los valores que le pasas a la función al momento de llamarla, esos parámetros son en si variables cuyo valor será el que se pase al momento de hacer `diferencia([1,3,4],[3,8,7])` y en este caso `c1` tendría el valor de `[1,3,4]` y para `c2` sería `[3,8,7]`

Comment: No entro mucho en detalles de lo que ocurre internamente porque 1. No es el tema de la pregunta 2. Recién estas iniciando y creo que te confundirlas Podrías hacer una pregunta a cerca de eso pero recuerda agregar lo que investigarse y la duda concreta que tienes